# C# Do not define variable for not used out parameter

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to omit out parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740193/is-there-a-way-to-omit-out-parameter)

Instead of:

```
SomeType param3;
SomeMethodCall(param1, param2, out param3);
```

I want not to define param3 in the case I don't need its value.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Write a wrapper (overload) for the `SomeMethodCall` function without the out parameter.

Comment: No, but calling `param3 = notUsed` goes a long way.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way of doing that in C#.

Answer (score 1):

If `SomeMethodCall` is something you defined yourself then you can overload the method. If it's not then you can't.

Comment: Well I guess you could with an extension method or something.

Comment: @BoltClock Nice one :)  Forgot about that one.

Answer (score 0):

No, you'll have to actually create a variable of the correct type if you want to use a function that takes an `out` parameter.