# Is there a way to use out parameter as an optional parameter in C#?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Optional Output Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293627/optional-output-parameters)

I am currently working in a module wherein I need to add a new out parameter to a function which has been used in so many places! Instead of adding that new parameter everywhere i wish to make it as optional.
Is there a way to use out parameter as an optional parameter?
Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so.

But you can just overload the function with a new one using the out-parameter. This way you old code works as expected and the new one can use the now overload.